# Discord.py voice bot youtube_dl invalidate error

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

Creating a python discord voice bot using youtube_dl using this code for the play command:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, brief="This will play a song 'play [url]'", aliases=['pl'])
async def play(ctx, url:str):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = bot.voice_client_in(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, after=lambda: check_queue(server.id))
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
```

After running the command in the discord the song will play, but after some time if the link is a youtube video the song will stop and I get this error:

```
[tls @ 000001b884817cc0] Error in the pull function.
[matroska,webm @ 000001b88417a180] Read error
[tls @ 000001b884817cc0] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I've done some research and I think it's because the youtube link expires.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `'-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5'` as part of `before_options`.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, brief="This will play a song 'play [url]'", aliases=['pl'])
async def play(ctx, url:str):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = bot.voice_client_in(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, after=lambda: check_queue(server.id), before_options='-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5')
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
```